# Phonegap Android Resume Event Issues

Tags: android, events, cordova, resume

I have just finished the IOS phase of development for your companies app, which is all working perfectly.  One of the features the app has is a passcode lock screen, so when you come back to the app after looking at another app etc, it shows a passcode screen, similar to bank apps etc.

My Problem, is that on android the resume event is being called at different points to IOS, for example :

In the contact section, if you click on one of the phone number buttons, the alert comes up asking if you want to call the number, add to contacts etc.  If you cancel out of this dialogue the resume handler fires, which is annoying as it results in the passcode screen being displayed!

Has anyone else come across this, or can think of a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below line inside the activity tag in your manifest xml file.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
```

Comment: are you using any UI Framework like jQuery Mobile inside your phone gap application? did u add any pause/resume event listener in your app. If you added it, check the implementation of your callback function. ex. document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);